# Genus of complete $ k $-partite graph

Tags: graph-theory

What is the formula for the genus of a complete $ k $-partite graph, with partite set of size $n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k$, where $ k $ is an integer greater than or equal to $3$?

Comment: The genus of the complete tripartite graph $K_{mn,n,n}$ is shown to be $(mn-2)(n-1)/2$, for all natural numbers m and n (see A. T. White, {\em The genus of the complete tripartite graph $K_{mn,n,n}$}, J. Com. Theory, 7, 283-285 (1969)). I think the problem to find the formulae for the genus of a complete $k$-partite graph is still an open problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ has genus $\left\lceil\frac{(m-2)(n-2)}{4}\right\rceil$ (from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphGenus.html).

Bettayeb has a paper on the genus of complete multipartite graphs; see [Link](https://doi.org/10.1109/AICCSA.2010.5587024).

Comment: I wouldn't expect anything more to be known about multipartite graphs, but do you know of any conjectures about it?